# How to check to make sure all items in a list are of a certain type

Tags: python

I want to enforce that all items in a list are of type `x`. What would be the best way to do this? Currently I am doing an assert like the following:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
assert len(a) == len([i for i in a if isinstance(i, int)])
```

Where `int` is the type I'm trying to enforce here. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are making it a little too complex. You can just use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
assert all(isinstance(i, int) for i in a)

a = [1,2,3,4,5.5]
assert all(isinstance(i, int) for i in a)
# AssertionError
```

Comment: @DSilveiro It also has the advantage that if any of them are not int, then it doesn't unnecessarily check the remaining ones.

Answer (score 6):

You need to decide whether you are interested in also including any *subclass* of int. `isinstance(i, int)` will return `True` if `i` is `True` or `False` because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Whatever you do, you should certainly use `all` as Mark Meyer suggests. (And incidentally, one advantage of doing that over what you are doing with `len` is that if any fail the test then it doesn't needlessly check the remaining items, provided that you are using a generator and not building a list of results -- the fact that no `[`...`]` symbols used anywhere in the syntax gives a clue that this is the case.)

But if you are only interested in including actual `int` type itself, then you should do:

```
assert all(type(i) is int for i in a)
```

(If you *do* want to allow e.g. `bool`, then see Mark Meyer's answer.)

Answer (score 2):

In Python you need ro ask yourself if it is necessary? Normally you check data going in to a program, then rely on your programs structure to distribute appropriate types within itself. You could use Mypy and type annotations to help (statically). You could make runtime checks optional - part of a debug mode, for example.
In the past I have had to go out to the level of interacting systems where data checkers used in learning the system were then turned off and only used in debug. Other programs could have less costly checks, internal development would use the checkers, and third party code could have the checkers run on their releases. Data checking took time and I had to look for efficient solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the assertion to succeed most of the time, which I believe is the case as an enforcement in the real world, mapping items in the list to the `type` function and constructing a set with the output and asserting that it is equal to a set of type `int` would be faster than using `all` since the iterations are performed in C.

```
assert set(map(type, a)) == {int}
```

See timing demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/AstonishingGivingVirtualmachines

Comment: thanks, might be interesting to benchmark the results for the different answers.

Comment: If you expect this assertion to succeed most of the time in the real world, this solution would be quite a bit faster than using `all` since the iterations are performed in C. See demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/AstonishingGivingVirtualmachines

Answer (score 0):

You can use all(), very simple but powerful

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
assert all(isinstance(i, int) for i in a)
```